# Difference between total transaction lifetime timeout and Maximum transaction timeout?

Tags: java, transactions, websphere

I am having confusion between total transaction lifetime timeout and Maximum transaction timeout of Transaction Service of Web Sphere .
could any body help me out in understanding the differences between the two ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the most important is the transactions they affect:

Timeout setting & Transactions affected

Maximum transaction timeout
All transactions running in this server that are not affected by the total transaction lifetime timeout or an application component timeout. These transactions include transactions imported from outside this server, such as those imported from a client.

Total transaction lifetime timeout
All transactions that originated in this server that are not affected by an application component timeout, in other words, the associated application component does not set its own timeout.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/udat_contranserv.html